# Why can't I get two lists from one list comprehension?

Tags: python

So I have an array of the following form:

```
[(1, u'first_type', u'data_gid_1'), 
 (2, u'first_type', u'data_gid_2'), 
 (3, u'first_type', u'data_gid_3'), 
 (4, u'first_type', u'data_gid_4')]
```

Now I want to extract the first and the last element of each inside list into separate lists. So if I do:

```
>>> ids = [dat[0] for dat in all_data]
>>> gds = [dat[2] for dat in all_data]
```

This works as I expect it to. However I was trying to merge these two into one call, something like:

```
 (ids, gds) = [(dat[0], dat[2]) for dat in all_data]
```

This however fails with an:
     `ValueError: too many values to unpack`

So could anyone explain why this is happening and if what I am trying to do is even possible.

Regards,
Bogdan

Comment: Is there anything wrong with leaving it as two lines? I mean sometimes its just nice to be clear.

Comment: Nothing wrong, that's still the solution I'm using, I just wanted to understand why I was getting the error for future uses.

Comment: @Bogdan That is truly honorable. I would give you a +1 for that comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't work because the length of `[(dat[0], dat[2]) for dat in all_data]` is the same as the lenght of `all_data`, which is not the same length as the tuple `(ids, gds)`.

Try this instead:

```
(ids, gds) = zip(*[(dat[0], dat[2]) for dat in all_data])
```

or even shorter:

```
(ids, gds) = zip(*all_data)[::2]
```

As noted in another answer, `ids` and `gds` will now be tuples, so if you need lists, do like this:

```
(ids, gds) = map(list, zip(*all_data)[::2])
```

---

The `zip(*something)` is a rather frequently occuring idiom in python. If you look at a list of lists as a matrix, i.e.

```
l = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6]]
```

Then `zip(*l)` transposes that matrix:

```
zip(*l) == [(1, 4),
            (2, 5),
            (3, 6)]
```

The `*` works like this: `some_func(*some_list)` *unpacks* `some_list` so that the function is in effect called with the elements of `some_list` as arguments. So `zip(*l)` is the same as `zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])`. [Here's](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) the relevant part of the python tutorial.

[`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) acts like a [zipper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper), hence the name, so it returns a list with these elements: a tuple of all the first elements of the given arguments, followed by a tuple of all the second elements, etc.

Comment: Nice.  Though a slightly better explanation to help the OP: "'Too many values to unpack' occurs because you are trying to assign a 4-element list to a 2-element tuple." +1.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. Got in now.

Comment: Was meaning to ask what is it exactly that zip() does. Thanks for clarifying. Will accept as soon as time expires.

Comment: @lazyr Definitely a +1 for this.

Answer (score 4):

Code below will also do the trick:

```
data = [(1, u'first_type', u'data_gid_1'), 
 (2, u'first_type', u'data_gid_2'), 
 (3, u'first_type', u'data_gid_3'), 
 (4, u'first_type', u'data_gid_4')]

ids, gds = ([row[i] for row in data] for i in [0,2])
```

Answer (score 1):

`[(dat[0], dat[2]) for dat in all_data]` means that you're creating a list of tuples `(dat[0],dat[2])`. It does not mean you have two lists, one of `d[0]` and the other of `d[2]`.

You could simply use `zip`, but that will result in tuples. If you want lists, you'll have to apply `list` to the result:

```
(ids, gds) = map(list,zip(*[(dat[0], dat[2]) for dat in a]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating two separate lists, try this:

```
ids, dgs = [(dat[0]) for dat in all_data], [(dat[2]) for dat in all_data]
```

or you can unpack it to a single list with the command you used:

```
x = [(dat[0], dat[2]) for dat in all_data]
```